Resemblance to girl killed by subway
I am looking for the name of a TV show that I saw sometime around 2015. 
A girl takes over the identity of someone that was hit by a subway train. She picked up the dead girl's wallet from the platform and noticed an uncanny resemblance. She went to the dead girls house and realized she had a good life, with lots of money. But realized there could be more to why she died. 
The girl also had a young daughter being raised by a grandmother(maybe). 
She also had a very gay hilarious best friend.

This sounds like the BBC's Orphan Black:

A streetwise hustler is pulled into a compelling conspiracy after witnessing the suicide of a girl who looks just like her.


That's it ! Thanks....you're awesome.

If this solved your question, don't forget to check the green checkmark to the left!
